# Get sums of rows with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors, sum, dom-node

I am trying to create a simple totaller, my basic html looks like this:

```
<ul>
    <li class="header">
        <span>&nbsp;</span>
        ...
        <span>Total</span>
    </li>
    <li>
        <span>0</span>
        <span>1</span>
        <span>2</span>
        <span>3</span>
        <span>4</span>
        <span>5</span>
        <span class="total">0</span>
    </li>
    <li>
        <span>1</span>
        <span>10</span>
        <span>20</span>
        <span>30</span>
        <span>40</span>
        <span>50</span>
        <span class="total">0</span>
    </li>
    <li>
        <span>5</span>
        <span>1</span>
        <span>1</span>
        <span>9</span>
        <span>3</span>
        <span>2</span>
        <span class="total">0</span>
    </li>
</ul>
```

jQuery function:

```
var eaList = $('ul li span').not('.total, .header span');
var sum = 0;
eaList.each(function(){
    var total = $(this).parent().find('.total');
    sum += parseFloat($(this).text());
    total.text(sum);
});
```

This is currently cumulatively adding to the total at the end of the function, not by row.

I was hoping it would be a case of a simple selector `var total = $(this).parent().find('.total');` (I have also tried `var total = $(this).closest('.total');`.

Do I need an empty array to push the total to before outputting the sum to the `.total` element? Or is there something in built in jquery which should return the sum using the correct selector?

JSFIDDLE: https://jsfiddle.net/lharby/y991hkf6/

Comment: [**Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/1xqoy57d/)

Comment: I think you take the problem in the wrong way. You should go throught your "li" elements, and then, get the spans within. You won't then have this issue

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The selector `$('ul li span').not('.total, .header span');` will select all the `span`s except those classes and add them and update the total in the DOM.

Use nested `each` to get the textContent of spans and add them.

```
// Get all the `li`s inside `ul` except header
$('ul li:not(.header)').each(function () {

    // Initialize total to zero
    var total = 0;

    // Get all the spans inside current `li`
    // except the `.total`
    $(this).find('span:not(.total)').each(function () {

        // Add the value to total
        // If no value, then add zero
        total += Number($(this).text()) || 0;
    });

    // Update the total in the `.total` of current `li`
    $('.total', this).text(total);
});
```

```js
$('ul li:not(.header)').each(function() {
 var total = 0;
    $(this).find('span:not(.total)').each(function() {
        total += Number($(this).text()) || 0;
    });
    $('.total', this).text(total);
});
```

```css
body {
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size: 11px;
    background: #F3F5F6;
}

ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

li {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0 1px 3px 0;
}

.header span {
    background: none;
}

span {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 25px;
    height: 25px;
    background: #FFF;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 25px;
}

.total {
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 1.2em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
    <li class="header">
        <span>&nbsp;</span>
        <span>&nbsp;</span>
        <span>&nbsp;</span>
        <span>&nbsp;</span>
        <span>&nbsp;</span>
        <span>&nbsp;</span>
        <span>Total</span>
    </li>
    <li>
        <span>0</span>
        <span>1</span>
        <span>2</span>
        <span>3</span>
        <span>4</span>
        <span>5</span>
        <span class="total">0</span>
    </li>
    <li>
        <span>1</span>
        <span>10</span>
        <span>20</span>
        <span>30</span>
        <span>40</span>
        <span>50</span>
        <span class="total">0</span>
    </li>
    <li>
        <span>5</span>
        <span>1</span>
        <span>1</span>
        <span>9</span>
        <span>3</span>
        <span>2</span>
        <span class="total">0</span>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just total the siblings!

```js
$(".total").each(function() {
  var total = 0;
  $(this).siblings().each(function() {
    total += parseInt($(this).text());
  });
  $(this).text(total);
});
```

```css
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 11px;
}
ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
li {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0 1px 3px 0;
}
.header span {
  background: none;
}
span {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  background: #FFF;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 25px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li class="header">
    <span>&nbsp;</span>
    <span>&nbsp;</span>
    <span>&nbsp;</span>
    <span>&nbsp;</span>
    <span>&nbsp;</span>
    <span>&nbsp;</span>
    <span>Total</span>
  </li>
  <li>
    <span>0</span>
    <span>1</span>
    <span>2</span>
    <span>3</span>
    <span>4</span>
    <span>5</span>
    <span class="total">0</span>
  </li>
  <li>
    <span>1</span>
    <span>10</span>
    <span>20</span>
    <span>30</span>
    <span>40</span>
    <span>50</span>
    <span class="total">0</span>
  </li>
  <li>
    <span>5</span>
    <span>1</span>
    <span>1</span>
    <span>9</span>
    <span>3</span>
    <span>2</span>
    <span class="total">0</span>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thank you. I find it quite simple and effective.  I'm just a little late to the party.

Comment: The less verbose scripting, the better in my opinion. I am also interested in more modular code. So this is great, thank you.

Answer (score -1):

```
Try this:
$('ul li:not(.header)').each(function () {
    var sum = $(this).find('span:not(.total)').map(function () { 
        return parseFloat($(this).text()); 
    }).get().reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0);

    $(this).find('.total').text(sum);
});
```

Comment: I didn't vote on it and the code might well work, but you should add a comment to show your working.